# LibreOffice Writter font selection menu is laggy

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Everything is running great except LibreOffice writer font selection menu. Whenever i click on it, it takes some time to response. Then whenever i turn scroll wheel up or down, it lags very badly.
Other options runs great except this one.
I want a quick effective solution please. Thanks in advance.

My spec,
Intel pentium G4560,
8GB of 2400mhz ram,
Zotac Nvidia Gt 1030,
Transcend 240GB m.2 ssd.

Comment: Maybe uninstall some font packages whose fonts you don't need. But be cautious so you don't uninstall  important packages which depend on certain font packages.

Comment: No. It's not working sir.

Comment: Then I would advise you to submit a bug report: `ubuntu-bug libreoffice`